# Having issues passing user inputted values from one function to another C

Tags: c

I'm making a tic tac toe game and when the user inputs their move I need to make sure the randomly generated numbers aren't the same as the users, and if they are to regenerate another move. The issue arrises when I have one function that gets the players move, then another that generates the random move. I can't seem to get the values for row and col from get_player1_move into generate_player2_move.

Here is my main function where I declare the row and col variables.

```
int main (){
char board[SIZE][SIZE];
int row, col;


clear_table(board);  //Clears the table
display_table(board);  //Display the table
do {
    get_player1_move(board, row, col); 
    printf("%d, %d", row, col);     //Have player 1 enter their move
    generate_player2_move(board, row, col); //Generate player 2 move
} while(check_end_of_game(board) == false); //Do this while the game hasn't ended

print_winner(board); //after game is over, print who won

 return 0;
}
```

Here is the get_player1_move function where I get the value that will go into row and col.

```
void get_player1_move(char board[SIZE][SIZE], int row, int col) {     //More work; test if game is over

printf("Player 1 enter your selection [row, col]: ");
scanf("%d, %d", &row, &col);

board[row-1][col-1] = 'O';
display_table(board);
}
```

Now I want to pass the values assigned to those two variables to this function so I can check it against the randomly generated move, but when I print out the values it keeps printing 0, 0. So for some reason I can't get the values to pass to this function. Here is the generate_player2_move function.

```
void generate_player2_move(char board[SIZE][SIZE], int row, int col) {   //More work; test if game is over, also the check doesn't work

int randrow = 0, randcol= 0;

srand(time(NULL));

randrow= rand() % 3 + 1;

randcol= rand() % 3 + 1;

printf("%d, %d\n", row, col);

if ((randrow != row) && (randcol != col)) {

printf("Player 2 has enterd [row, col]: %d, %d \n", randrow, randcol);

board[randrow - 1][randcol - 1] = 'X';

display_table(board);
}
}
```

When I run that function the printf("%d, %d\n", row, col); continues to print 0, 0 when I would like it to print the values the user entered in the previous function.

Comment: Just to clarify both `printf()` calls (the first in the `main()` and the second in the `generate_player2_move()`) outputs `0, 0`. Is that right?

Comment: What about move 4? First player has made 2 moves, 2nd player has made 1 move; it's 2nd player turn again. Do you still want to pass `row` and `col`? Remember you already pass the current `board` around...

Comment: Do you know how parameter passing works in C functions? Your board is an array, but row and col are ints.

Comment: @BenjaminJ. the first printf that occurs in the `main()` prints out the user input correctly. It's the one in `generate_player2_move()` that outputs `0, 0.`

Comment: @JackBurtenshaw: Are you sure? I've tested it and both `printf()` calls (the first in the `main()` function and the second in the `generate_player2_move()` outputs `0, 0`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple issues in your program.

First let's get to the reason why your `printf()` call outputs `0, 0`. The parameters `row` and `col` are all local variables which are passed by value. That means if e. g. the `row` variable get's changed within the `get_player1_move()` function via the `scanf()` call, it doesn't change outside of the `get_player1_move()` function. So the variable `row` in the `main()` function remains unchanged.

You could solve that with using pass by reference (pointers). But the problem is that your function for player 2 only checks the last row and column selected by player 1. But you have to check all rows and columns. Otherwise a field could get be overwritten.

Comment: I will edit the function to work properly in that way once I am able to get the values into the function correctly. So I need to use pointers for this? Also excuse me, I'm brand new to coding.

Comment: Yes, you could do it with pointers. But that isn't the correct way. You already have the variable `board` within your functions. You just have to check on the generated number if the field is free or not. If it's in use just generate a new one, until you have found a free field. The same thing you have to do in the `get_player1_move()` function.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't even think of that, that makes more sense. I'll give that a shot, thanks!

Comment: No problem. I'm happy if I could help you. If you're question is solved, please make sure to accept the answer, so that others can see that this question is solved. Thanks!